# GA Measurement Protocol: All events showing as unique

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using the new [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#) and running into a problem where all my events are coming is as "new visitor" even though I'm sending the same client ID for all of the requests.

I assume Google is using the client ID to determine if a visitor is new or not, but it appears to be ignoring this value.

Here's the variables I'm sending in the POST request:

```
Array
(
    [v] => 1
    [tid] => *OBFUSCATED*
    [cid] => E19A0922-ABDF-D704-E4D4-620FB7AD7885
    [t] => event
    [sr] => 1280x720
    [ec] => Video%20Plays
    [ea] => Sample
    [el] => Roku%20App
    [ev] => 1
)
```

Other events are similar, where the cid remains the same but the event category and values change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like after waiting a full day and sending some events again, they are showing as returning visits.

Comment: Could you explain how did you generated this client ID? I have some problems identifying ecommerce transactions and looks like my cid is wrong. I am sending cid what i get from tracker but it's way different than yours (two integers separated with a dot). Thanks!

Comment: If you look below, you can see there's some discussion on the proper way to present a CID. At the time there was conflicting evidence in the docs on how to format the CID. This one that I made was just a UUID. Many languages have code in them that can generate a UUID for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your cid is wrong I guess. it should be a 32bit id separated from a dot. Find a actual case study in my blog post http://www.niroshan-samuel.com/google-universal-analytics-isnt-linking-offline-and-online-user-properly/

Comment: According tot he documentation, the CID should be a UUID: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid. But it also references it as just an integer ID here as well: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference. So, maybe I'll try with an integer and see if that makaes a difference

Comment: @Brian, Google does not really care what you put in there, the recommendation for a UUID is only because that is a surefire way to avoid collisions (if client ids repeat, different users will be recognized as being the same).